# Can someone please provide an example of iterating over directories using tokio::fs?

Tags: file, rust, async-await, directory, rust-tokio

I am building a somewhat basic logging server in Rust and have been using Tokio for async TCP connections. It's bee great for that. I need to store data coming in over TCP in JSON format into separate files. It's to make it easier to graph each logging session.
So, I've been adding some basic file functionality. My TCP code is inside a Tokio::spawn, which didn't seem like a problem until I realized I couldn't use .await? calls that most Tokio crate examples provide.
In any event, right now I am pounding my head against the wall trying to figure out the most basic thing, iterating over the files in a directory. It's shocking how something so simple has been so insanely difficult. All I do is read_dir, which requires an await. Inside the while loop iterating over the entries, I am simply getting the file_name() of the DirEntry and converting it from OsString to &str so I can compare it later. I add each one to a Vec<&str>. That's the whole problem. it looks like this:

```
let mut subdirs: Vec<&str> = Vec::new();
        while let entry = entries.next_entry().await.unwrap().unwrap() {
            let v = entry.file_name().as_os_str().to_str().unwrap();
            subdirs.push(v);
        }
```

When I do this, it gives me the error :

> temporary value dropped while borrowed
> consider using a `let` binding to create a longer lived value

I've tried a million different variations of getting the value. I also want to be able to check if the entries are directories, because I only want a list fo the directories. For crying out loud, I just want to see if a certain directory exists or not.

Okay, so I am new to Rust. I'm hoping this is some new person overlooked simple thing. I just wish the Tokio docs had actual examples of this stuff. I've scoured everywhere for some async file system code and can't find any.

Let me know if you need more code. I've made such a mess of mine hacking away at this I didn't think it would be helpful to include what has become spaghetti code filled with commented out attempts to fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`into_string()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/ffi/struct.OsString.html#method.into_string) or [`to_string_lossy().to_string()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/ffi/struct.OsString.html#method.to_string_lossy) instead of the borrowing `as_os_str`:

```rust
let mut subdirs: Vec<String> = Vec::new();
while let entry = entries.next_entry().await.unwrap().unwrap() {
    let v = entry.file_name().into_string().unwrap();
    subdirs.push(v);
}
```

`entry.file_name()` goes out of scope at the end of the staement so you can't borrow from it.